# AngularJS two-way binding in route templates when using routeProvider templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have an app where the sidebar will show a list of to do messages, and a list of processed messages (navigate with tabs), and clicking on it will show the details of the message on the main section to the right of the sidebar.  The view on the right has some form inputs whwere the user fills out the details of the message, press a button, and the message is moved from to-do to processed.

```
  <div id="sidebar" data-ng-controller="MessageController">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="message-tab">
      <li><a href="#to-do" data-toggle="tab">To-do</a></li>
      <li><a href="#processed" data-toggle="tab">Processed</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="to-do">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="message in todoMessages | orderBy: id">
              <td>
                  <a href="#/todo/{{message.id}}" class=""><span>{{message.name}}  </span></a> <small style="float:right;">{{message.type}}</small>
              </td>
            </tr>

       </table>

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="processed">
        <table class="table table-hover">

            <tr data-ng-repeat="message in processedMessages | orderBy: id">
              <td>
                <a href="#/processed/{{message.id}}" class=""><span>{{message.name}}  </span></a> <small style="float:right;">{{message.type}}</small>
              </td>
            </tr> 

       </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main-panel">
    <div class="message-preview " data-ng-view="">
    </div>            
  </div>
```

The problem I am having is that the main section on the right uses ng-view with the $routeProvider providing the template when the URL hash changes.  When trying to update a $scope object in the template view, the sidebar's lists does not update.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('messageApp', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/todo/:messageId',
                    {
            controller: 'MessageController',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/todoView.html'
                    })
     .when('/processed/:messageId',
                    {
            controller: 'MessageController',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/processedView.html'
                    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

However, if I put the same markup that's in the sidebar into the template view, the two-way binding works properly as I can see that the list updates when manipulating the scope objects.

What am I doing wrong and how can I have the sidebar using ng-controller update properly?

Comment: Controllers aren't singletons so you end up with two instances of your controller that do not share $scope. If you need to communicate between them you could either dispatch events on $rootScope or create a service that holds the shared data.